# How to import another view controller header file when I use Objective-C category?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I want to transition from one view controller to another, I import the second view controller's header file into my first view controller's header file, by writing `#import "SecondViewController.h"`. However, since I already defined `UIColor` category in my first view controller, when I try to import the second view controller, I enter the following error: `Duplicate interface definition class for SecondViewController`.

Here's my `FirstViewController.h`:

```
#import 
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface UIColor (ColorWithInt)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithR:(CGFloat)red G:(CGFloat)green B:(CGFloat)blue A:(CGFloat)alpha;
@end
```

I didn't meet any such errors so far when I develop this app, so it's definitely this category that is causing the issue here. So is it feasible to use category when I want to import another view controller class? Or are there any alternative ways to extend `UIColor`? I just want to define a function that takes RGB as 0 ~ 255 integer, not 0 ~ 1 floating values that `UIColor` uses on default.

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the category, can you post your SecondViewController code?

Comment: Why are you declaring the `UIColor` interface in the header file for a view controller? Put your category in its own .h and .m to avoid this.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy There's zero reason for a `Foundation` class category to be crammed into a view controller header.  That's just silly.  Now ANY class that needs to use this category has to import a view controller's header.

Comment: rmaddy, is it impossible to use category in this way? One blog article that I've read to define this category wrote it in this way. I'll try your recommended approach though.

Comment: I moved my category to another class (`UIColor+ColorWithInt`) and imported it in my `FirstViewController.h`, it worked. However, I still cannot import `SecondViewController` due to the same duplication error.

Comment: Why are you importing `SecondViewController.h` into `FirstViewController.h`? Do you reference `SecondViewController` in the interface of `FirstViewController`? If so, show that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Self Answer

I found out that the issue is not related to either `FirstViewController` or `SecondViewController` - let alone the category; it's because I imported almost all class' header file in `AppDelegate.h` in order to initialize the relationship among `UITabBarController`, `UINavitationController`, `RootViewController`, and Core Data and its lots of required properties. I didn't know that when I import a class in `AppDelegate.h` I cannot import the class at some other class's header file. Delete `#import "FirstViewController.h";` and `#import "SecondViewController.h;"` in `AppDelegate.h` and I find my app being build properly now. Thanks to those who left comments in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You might `#import "SecondViewController.h"` twice, just check `FirstViewController.h/m` file if both did that.

Comment: I did check it out numerous times before posing this question, but there's only one import statement there. Actually, when I removed the import statement and still tried to instantiate `SecondViewController` instance, I got an error.

Comment: @user2360798 and did you check the `Build Phases` if `SecondViewController` be added twice?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're using this

```
@interface
```

instead of

```
@implementation
```

in your .m file.